# Can't install grpc npm-package

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, grpc

I have a problem with grpc npm-package.
When I run a `npm i` it starts with:

```
> grpc@1.24.2 install C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
```

then there is a lot errors with node-gyp, **that starts with**:

```
PS C:\RELOG\relog> npm i fcm-node                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> grpc@1.24.2 install C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@12.16.2 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error connect ETIMEDOUT 104.28.23.74:443
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.vcxproj -> C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\WINDOWS_BUILD_WARNING.node
  address_sorting.c
  address_sorting_posix.c
  address_sorting_windows.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  address_sorting.vcxproj -> C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\libaddress_sorting.lib
  ares__close_sockets.c
  ares__get_hostent.c
  ares__read_line.c
  ares__timeval.c
  ares_cancel.c
  ares_create_query.c
  ares_data.c
  ares_destroy.c
  ares_expand_name.c
  ares_expand_string.c
  ares_fds.c
  ares_free_hostent.c
  ares_free_string.c
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\cares\cares\ares__get_hostent.c(141,32): warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnin
gs [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\ares.vcxproj]
  ares_getenv.c
  ares_gethostbyaddr.c
  ares_gethostbyname.c
  ares_getnameinfo.c
  ares_getopt.c
  ares_getsock.c
  ares_init.c
  ares_library_init.c
  ares_llist.c
  ares_mkquery.c
  ares_nowarn.c
  ares_options.c
  ares_parse_a_reply.c
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\cares\cares\ares_gethostbyname.c(275,32): warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warni
ngs [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\ares.vcxproj]
  ares_parse_aaaa_reply.c
  ares_parse_mx_reply.c
  ares_parse_naptr_reply.c
  ares_parse_ns_reply.c
  ares_parse_ptr_reply.c
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\cares\cares\ares_init.c(2421,18): warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings [C:\
RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\ares.vcxproj]
  ares_parse_soa_reply.c
  ares_parse_srv_reply.c
  ares_parse_txt_reply.c
  ares_platform.c
  ares_process.c
  ares_query.c
  ares_search.c
  ares_send.c
  ares_strcasecmp.c
  ares_strdup.c
  ares_strerror.c
  ares_strsplit.c
  ares_timeout.c
  ares_version.c
  ares_writev.c
  bitncmp.c
  inet_net_pton.c
  inet_ntop.c
  windows_port.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  ares.vcxproj -> C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\libares.lib
  err_data.c
  a_bitstr.c
  a_bool.c
  a_d2i_fp.c
  a_dup.c
  a_enum.c
  a_gentm.c
  a_i2d_fp.c
  a_int.c
  a_mbstr.c
  a_object.c
  a_octet.c
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(147,1): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\no
de_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\Users\crimpyhead\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\12.16.2\include\node\openssl\opensslv.h(42): message : see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\no
de_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\Users\crimpyhead\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\12.16.2\include\node\openssl\e_os2.h(171,1): warning C4005: 'OPENSSL_EXPORT': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules
\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(182): message : see previous definition of 'OPENSSL_EXPORT' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modul
es\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\Users\crimpyhead\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\12.16.2\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(91,26): error C2371: 'EVP_MD': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\no
de_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(304): message : see declaration of 'EVP_MD' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\bo
ringssl.vcxproj]
C:\Users\crimpyhead\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\12.16.2\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(92,30): error C2371: 'EVP_MD_CTX': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relo
g\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(303): message : see declaration of 'EVP_MD_CTX' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\buil
d\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\Users\crimpyhead\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\12.16.2\include\node\openssl\ossl_typ.h(100,34): error C2371: 'EVP_ENCODE_CTX': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG
\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(308): message : see declaration of 'EVP_ENCODE_CTX' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\
build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\Users\crimpyhead\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\12.16.2\include\node\openssl\crypto.h(231,3): error C2371: 'CRYPTO_THREADID': redefinition; different basic types (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\r
elog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\third_party\boringssl\include\openssl\base.h(231): message : see declaration of 'CRYPTO_THREADID' (compiling source file ..\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c) [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc
\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(33,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(34,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(35,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(36,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(37,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(38,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(39,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(40,1): error C2065: 'ERR_LIB_PKCS8': undeclared identifier [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(40,1): error C2057: expected constant expression [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(40,1): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0 [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(41,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(42,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(43,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(44,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(45,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\deps\grpc\src\boringssl\err_data.c(46,1): error C2118: negative subscript [C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\build\boringssl.vcxproj]
```

and in the end it shows this:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\RELOG\\relog\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\RELOG\\relog\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\RELOG\\relog\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\RELOG\relog\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN babel-loader@6.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN leaflet-textpath@1.2.3 requires a peer of leaflet@^1.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1 requires a peer of leaflet@~1.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-leaflet@1.9.1 requires a peer of leaflet@^1.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-tooltip@3.11.6 requires a peer of react@>=^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-tooltip@3.11.6 requires a peer of react-dom@>=^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-visjs-timeline@1.6.0 requires a peer of vis-timeline@^5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grpc@1.24.2 (node_modules\grpc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

I have an Windows 10
VS 2017 with Dev C++
python2.7 added to PATH
Every thing that is included here https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration

Also, I have tried to install grpc alone `npm i grpc`. But it gives the same error.

Comment: Can you share the beginning of the error output?

Comment: @murgatroid99, I've included in a row **starts with**. Also, I find out that it is because of package fcm-node, which depends on grpc. Haven't gone anything else:(

Comment: That's not the beginning of your error output. You may need to change your terminal settings to keep more lines.

Comment: @murgatroid99, I've included from my script run

Comment: Or is this because of this node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error connect ETIMEDOUT 104.28.23.74:443? I didn't mention it because of WARN

Comment: That error is the problem. It means that you failed to connect to the server that provides the binary packages that `grpc` uses, so it tried to fall back to building from source, but that doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Thank you!

Comment: @murgatroid99 facing the same issue, any idea where to find the server details to which it tries to connect to for the binaries - it's not in the detailed output.
Facing the issue only on windows - for mac, it works fine.

Comment: @AmanGupta The `grpc` package has been deprecated for over two years, and it is not compatible with recent versions of Node, so the more likely explanation is that you are encountering that incompatibility. I recommend switching to `@grpc/grpc-js`

Comment: @AmanGupta as addition to murgatorid99's answer, you may try to downgrade you node version to use old grpc package

Comment: @YerbolSuleimanov Downgrading node is NOT a good option and also, not a viable one for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for those with this error, it is because of the node version, you must use an older version.

Take this repo https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/uni-orders for example, with node 18, I get the same error:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.22.15
$ cp src/orders/orders.proto dist/orders/orders.proto && nest start
[Nest] 68342   - 08/02/2022, 2:47:32 PM   [PackageLoader] The "grpc" package is missing. Please, make sure to install this library ($ npm install grpc) to take advantage of ServerGrpc.
```

But with node 16, it works fine:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ cp src/orders/orders.proto dist/orders/orders.proto && nest start
[Nest] 71355   - 08/02/2022, 2:50:31 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 71355   - 08/02/2022, 2:50:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] ClientsModule dependencies initialized +103ms
[Nest] 71355   - 08/02/2022, 2:50:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 71355   - 08/02/2022, 2:50:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] ShoppingCartModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 71355   - 08/02/2022, 2:50:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution was to install grpc globally.

```
npm install grpc -g
```

Comment: We get a warning to use grpc/grpc-js instead

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't install/run my project in windows. So the solution was to install WSL.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me today is building it from source using,

```
npm install grpc --build-from-source
```

Comment: For what it's worth, on node v16.13.1 MacOS Monterey, `yarn global add grpc` keeps failing, but installing it this way (using npm) worked!

Answer (score 0):

Working for me only when I used node version 8.16.2

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to resolve the issue.

- Delete the `node_modules` folder.
- Install grpc using the following command

  ```
  npm install grpc
  ```
- Install other dependencies using the following command

  ```
  npm install --force
  ```
- If you are getting node sass related errors in your project then use the following commands to resolve that issue.

  ```
  npm uninstall node-sass
  npm install node-sass@4.14.1
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me was to delete the places that had **grpc** in *package-lock.js* and run `npm install`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).